# Fast socket networking library for C++

Tags: library, c++, networking

Can somebody advice fast client-server C++ TCP(or reliable UDP) networking library?

Maybe like RakNet.

Comment: What features do you need exactly? Other than "fast".

Comment: @Alejandro, TCP packet exchange, support encryption or attaching plugins for add encryption, crossplatform.

Comment: Please update your question with the details you provided in the comments section (and any more details you think will help you get helpful recommendations).  Also please let us know a price range as well as OS compatibility of the libraries.  Thanks!